# How to save specific attachment with date stamp from outlook inbox to specific folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, email-filter, microsoft-outlook-2016

Every morning I receive an email containing 3 files:

```
"Daily MILH Checks e.xls"
"Daily Unit Linked .pdf"
"Daily Unit Linked.xls"
```

That is 2x .xls and a PDF. File names never change.

The email comes from `"sender@hotmail.com"` with the flowing subject line:

```
"IA083A - (Date: May 23, 2016)"
```

I created a rule which runs a macro every time an email is received from `"sender@hotmail.com"` with `"IA083A"` in the subject line.

[image]

I know the code posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/504348/automatically-save-attachments-from-mail-matching-a-specific-rule) is a starting point for what i need.

```
Public Sub SaveToDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat

dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

'Change this path to the your folder location
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & ".xls"

Set objAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above does not distinguish between different files. Each of my 3 files needs to be saved to a separate folder location.

The above renames the file "yyyy-mm-dd" before saving. I would like it to preserve part of the name of the file and add the date at the end. eg. "Checks Report 23-05-2016"

Comment: What folders are you trying to get each file to go to? What have you tried already? How far have you gotten? This site does not write scripts for you.

Answer (score 0):

The other post you reference links to [PixelChelf](http://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook) which has all the elements you need to save each file to their respective folders with a date stamp.

Comment: Thanks for the comment however you may have missunderstood my issue. i would like to save each of the above attachements in 3 separate folders

Comment: your suggestion saves all 3 files from 1 email in the same folder. Could you maybe provide more details on how you can do it using rules? All i can see is "run a macro" when you receive mail from x@ddd.com. After changing the location folder in the code the files are all saved in 1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a bat file to move these attachments from the saved path to your destination location.
And you can call that bat file from this code above.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub SaveToDisk_MultipleFolders(itm As Object)

Dim objAtt As Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
Dim saveFileName As String

Dim dateFormat As String

Dim posDot As Long
Dim fNameNoExt As String
Dim fExt As String

If TypeOf itm Is MailItem Then

    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "objAtt.DisplayName: " & objAtt.DisplayName
        
        saveFolder = ""
        
        If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Daily MILH Checks.xls") Then
            saveFolder = "c:\MILHChecks\"
                
        ElseIf InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Daily Unit Linked.pdf") Then
            saveFolder = "c:\UnitLinkedPDF\"
            
        ElseIf InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Daily Unit Linked.xls") Then
            saveFolder = "c:\UnitLinkedXLS\"
            
        End If
        
        If saveFolder <> "" Then
        
            If Right(saveFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                saveFolder = saveFolder & "\"
            End If
            Debug.Print " saveFolder: " & saveFolder
                
            posDot = InStrRev(objAtt.DisplayName, ".")
            Debug.Print " posDot: " & posDot
                
            fNameNoExt = Left(objAtt.DisplayName, posDot - 1)
            Debug.Print " fNameNoExt: " & fNameNoExt
            
            fExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, Len(objAtt.DisplayName) - posDot + 1)
            Debug.Print " fExt: " & fExt
            
            saveFileName = fNameNoExt & "_" & dateFormat & fExt
            
            Debug.Print " saveFileName: " & saveFileName
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & saveFileName
                
            Set objAtt = Nothing
            
        Else
            
            Debug.Print "saveFolder error: " & objAtt.DisplayName
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
End If

End Sub


Private Sub test()
    SaveToDisk_MultipleFolders ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Sub
```